# Problema ao pegar key de arquivo .resx

Tags: c#

Tenho uma `NullReferenceException` nesta linha:

```
string from = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("globalization", "mail_from").ToString();
```

porque ele não está encontrando o arquivo .resx, portanto não encontra o "mail_from" e dá `ToString()` em null.

Tenho o arquivo na pasta **App_GlobalResources**, chamado globalization.pt-BR.resx.

Comment: Se usar `Resources.globalization.ResourceManager.GetString("mail_from")` funciona?

Comment: @jbueno Funcionou, aproveitei e criei uma classe separada para tratar e facilitar a busca de strings, muito obrigado :). Se quiser fazer uma resposta pra eu colocar como respondida..

Comment: Por nada, adicionei a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sei qual o motivo disto não funcionar, mas você pode tentar do modo padrão

```
Resources.globalization.ResourceManager.GetString("mail_from‌​")
```