# Problema ao acessar um Resource pela minha classe C#

Tags: c#

O Problema está em um projeto que estou fazendo adicionei 2 recursos Main.resx quero pegar dados dentro desse Resource dessa forma:

```
    System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(System.Resources_example.Main));
```

tenho o recurso Main.resx no meu projeto mais não consigo acessa-lo System.Resources_example.Main nessa parte do codigo que ocorre o erro o Visual Studio não reconhece o recurso Main.resx

Comment: O que que é `System.Resources_example`? Você criou um resrouce com namespace de `System`? esse `typeof()`se refere ao classe gerado pelo `.resx`. Normalmente, esse classe não reside no `System` namespace

Comment: @Alan Maik, eu estava com um problema semelhante, vê se isso te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199035/problema-ao-pegar-key-de-arquivo-resx

Comment: @ArturoTemplário uma boa exemplo de como usar o resource: `Resources.Main`. O classe se basea no nome do arquivo.

Comment: O nome da Minha classe é System.Resources_example o nome do meu resource é Main.resx preciso acessar ele para consumir os recursos

Comment: Não é só acessar diretamente: `System.Resources_example.Main.???` o nome do recurso?

Comment: Então não consigo acessar o recurso quando coloco System.Resources_example. aparece para mim apenas a opção Program  não aparece meu Resource

Comment: Abra o resource design e verifique o namespace se é esse mesmo! ou coisa você deixou ele com `public`?

Comment: Resolvido alterando o namespace no Main.Designer.cs estava com o nome de outro projeto obrigado !